# iwlwifi error while installing kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, iwlwifi

I got this error and I couldn't find the mentionned files in the debian website . I tried to download the ISo again but the same problem remained .
Where can I find those files and should I put them on the kali usb stick or on another one ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you can connect TEMPORARILY by cable you don't need to pay any attention to this message.

You need to edit the sources list to make sure that the relevant lines include: contrib non-free

See https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Then, having connected TEMPORARILY by cable, you: `sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi`

2) If you CANNOT connect temporarily by cable then follow the instructions and put firmware-iwlwifi from another computer onto a usb stick during installation.

3) Reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks ,I didn't do anything and  the wifi worked as nothing happened ! I thought it wouldn't

Answer (score 2):

You can just skip this step and when the installation is over, install the package manually.

```
apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
rfkil unblock all
```

Comment: Thanks ,I didn't do anything and  the wifi worked as nothing happened ! I thought it wouldn't